# How do I get different images to display depending on the score in a quiz?

Tags: jquery, image

I need a gold crown to display if the user gets 5 points, a silver crown for 3-4 points, a bronze crown for 1-2 points, and a message saying try again if they get 0. This is what i've got so far.

```js
var questions = [{
  prompt: "What colour are apples?\n(a) Red/Green\n\(b) Purple\n(c) Orange",
  answer: "a"
}, {
  prompt: "What number comes between 4 and 6?\n(a) 19\n\(b) 3\n(c) 5",
  answer: "c"
}, {
  prompt: "Who won the 2020 US Presidential Election?\n(a) Donald Trump\n\(b) Joe Biden\n(c) Kanye West",
  answer: "b"
}, {
  prompt: "What year did man first walk on the moon?\n(a) 1969\n\(b) 2020\n(c) It hasn't happened yet",
  answer: "a"
}, {
  prompt: "How many questions have there been so far?\n(a) 5\n\(b) 4\n(c) 6",
  answer: "a"
}, ]

var score = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  var response = window.prompt(questions[i].prompt);
  if (response == questions[i].answer) {
    score++;
    alert("Correct");
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!");
  }
}
alert("you got " + score + "/" + questions.length);


function gold_crown(score) {
  if (score == 5)

    alert("You got them all right")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="images/goldcrown.png" alt="gold" width="500" height="500">;
```